# How to use threads in android efficiently to load images in recyclerview

Tags: android

Following is the issue-I want to load images from web and the decode them in background while splash activity is displayed to user. There are about 100+ images that need to be downloaded and decoded and then set into recyclerview I tried using intent service but that doesn't seem to work. Also,I want to do this concurrently so I'm  trying multi-threading.  Is intent service multi-threading also? If so, it should work, right? Just to be clear I know I can use Picasso, but I want to learn multithreading which will be helpful in other projects that I am starting.

```
 public class BackgroundClass implements Runnable {

@Override
public void run() {
    Process.setThreadPriority(Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);


           String image = RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
    .add("request",image)
    .build();
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
    .url(link)
    .post(formBody)
    .build();
    try  {
Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
response1 = response.body().string();
      } catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
    Log.i(TAG, "onHandleIntent: error: "+e.getMessage());

    }JSONArray webServiceResponse = null;
    try {
webServiceResponse = new JSONArray(response1);
for (int i = 0; i<webServiceResponse.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject row = webServiceResponse.getJSONObject(i);
    image = (row.getString("image"));
imageArray.add(image);
}
       } catch (JSONException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
Log.i(TAG, "onReceive: "+e.getMessage());
    }//code for recycler after this

  //Once recycler code is done following line of code should execute alongwith recyclerview adpter
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}
    }
```

The MainActivity is as following-

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash_activity);

   BackgroundClass backgroundClass = new BackgroundClass();
    backgroundClass.run();

  }

}
```

However, setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); does not get executed. Now as I saw on android documentation website, I can't set view object properties from a background thread. How do I get it  back to MainActivity()? Also this all need to happen simultaneousely. i.e. while splash activity is being displayed all of the other code should happen in background. I have used intent service for other purposes. But it doesn't seem to work here. Or I can't get it to work.
If there is any other multi threading technique I'm open to that too. I am not very experienced with multi threading so any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,
hyperCoder

Comment: You talk about `Intent` but you never use it in your code.

Comment: Use one of the many existing image-loading libraries, such as Glide or Picasso, rather than implementing your own.

Comment: Hi Niver, as I mentioned I tried but it didn't work. So I'm trying out this. Is intent type of multithreading?

Comment: Commonsware, I am aware of Picasso and have implemented it successfully. I want to learn multi threading and thats why trying this code

Answer (score 0):

Consider using an image loading library like [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) or [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide).

The libraries can download the images for you and display them in an `ImageView`. They also cache the images on disk and in memory.

Loading an image from network with Picasso looks like:

```
Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);
```

You can also use a placeholder image while your image is being downloaded.

Comment: I am getting images on from databse. I have stored it there in string format with base64 encoding. Can I still use Picasso for that?